# How to append in separate lists for every iteration of for loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I want to append in separate list for example: list1 for j=1, list 2 for j=2 and so on, similarly (total[j]= (sum(sum_list[j]/mcSteps-j)

**Here is  code :**

```
sum_list=[]
cor =[]

   
         for j in range(10):
             for i in range(mcSteps-j):
                 sum_list.append(Energy_list[i]*Energy_list[i+j])

        total[j]=sum(sum_list[j])
        deltat[j]=total[j]/(mcSteps-j)
        cor[j].append(Divide*(deltat[j]-E1mean*E1mean))
print('cor[j]')
```

Comment: Please take time to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Based on what you're saying, it sounds like you're looking to use the index of `j` to create separate lists – so in the code you have, you would have 10 separate lists, right?

Comment: Also, can you provide an example of what `Energy_list` should be?

Comment: @john yes i will have 10 separate lists and energy_list is a value returned from separate function: Energy_list.append(Ene)

Comment: Okay, cool. The example you've given appears to be missing pieces. e.g. `cor20` will only have a single value at the end of this evaluation and `cor` will be an empty list. Is this alright? Providing a more complete example allows for creating a more complete answer.

Comment: I have edited code example! I want to print 10 values for cor[j] for j=1 to 10

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend considering [`numpy`](http://numpy.org/) for something like this (from what it looks like). You can do many of these operations in far fewer lines – and it maintains wall-clock efficiency compared to Python lists and loops when you get to rather large numerical computations (around N=`10_000`).

Anywho, a solution to what you've asked for appears to be...

```py
from typing import List

def compute_delta_t(ls: List, steps: int, offset: int) -> float:
    energies = [ls[step] * ls[step + offset] for step in range(steps)]
    delta_t = sum(energies) / (steps - offset)
    return delta_t

delta_ts = [
    compute_delta_t(Energy_list, mcSteps, offset)
    for offset in range(10)
]
corrs = [Divide * (delta_t - (E1mean ** 2)) for delta_t in delta_ts]
```

The above approach should be rather efficient Python code (albeit getting untenable and unreadable).

---

`numpy`, an alternative for doing [matrix] math (among many other things) in Python.

```py
import numpy as np

def compute_delta_t(ls: np.ndarray, mcSteps: int, offset: int) -> np.ndarray:
    energies = ls[:(mcSteps - offset)] * ls[offset:(mcSteps + offset)]
    delta_t = energies.sum() / (mcSteps - offset)
    return delta_t

delta_ts = np.asarray([
    compute_delta_t(Energy_list, mcSteps, offset)
    for offset in range(10)
])
corrs = Divide * (delta_ts - (E1mean ** 2))
```

This `numpy`-based approach looks very similar to the Python approach explicitly because I'm not sure the each `np.ndarray` would have the same size. If they did, then most of what you're looking for could be accomplished in around 2-3 lines of code.

(For those who know what I'm talking about, I'm ignoring the possibility of padding with 0s.)

Comment: If this was a solution to your question, please mark it as such. 

Comment: with this answer I am getting error: list index out of range. Could you please tell how to fix it ?

Comment: Which implementation are you getting arrows with? Also, can you specify where this error's occurring? I don't have access to your entire set of lists. Realistically, it would be ideal if you can provide all of the values for variables defined here – like `Energy_list`, `E1Mean`, `Divide`, and so on. Then, I can properly revise my solution to fit your needs.